# Prove that $x=[\frac{x+2^0}{2^1}]+[\frac{x+2^1}{2^2}]+ \cdots +[\frac{x+2^{x-1}}{2^x}]$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $x$ be any positive integer. Prove that $x=[\frac{x+2^0}{2^1}]+[\frac{x+2^1}{2^2}]+ \cdots +[\frac{x+2^{x-1}}{2^x}]$

So I tried an example: I said let $x=2$

$$2=\left[\frac{2+2^0}{2^1}\right]+\left[\frac{2+2^1}{2^2}\right]+\left[\frac{2+2^2}{2^3}\right]+ \cdots +\left[\frac{2+2^{2-1}}{2^2}\right]=\frac{3}{2}+2+\frac{6}{8}+ \cdots +1$$

Regardless, this is not true.

Am i doing something wrong or does anyone agree this result is not true? If it is not true, then how am i suppose to prove it is true?

Comment: Here $[y]$ denotes the greatest integer not exceeding $y$.  Thus, you could never get $\frac 32$ as a value.  Taking $x=2$ the sum ought to read $\left[\frac {2+2^0}{2^1}\right]+\left[\frac {2+2^1}{2^2}\right]=\left[\frac {3}{2}\right]+\left[\frac {4}{4}\right]=1+1=2$

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the square brackets are supposed to denote the floor function, nowadays usually written $\lfloor x\rfloor$ rather than $[x]$. In other words, $\left\lfloor\frac{x+2^{k-1}}{2^k}\right\rfloor$ is the unique integer $n$ such that

$$n\le\frac{2+2^{k-1}}{2^k}<n+1\;.$$

Your example with $x=2$ is then

$$\sum_{k=1}^2\left\lfloor\frac{2+2^k}{2^{k+1}}\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor\frac{2+2^0}{2^1}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{2+2^1}{2^2}\right\rfloor=1+1=2\;,$$

which is fine. In general

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^x\left\lfloor\frac{x+2^{k-1}}{2^k}\right\rfloor&=\left\lfloor\frac{x+2^0}{2^1}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{x+2^1}{2^2}\right\rfloor+\ldots+\left\lfloor\frac{x+2^{x-1}}{2^x}\right\rfloor\\
&=\left\lfloor\frac{x}{2^1}+\frac12\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{x}{2^2}+\frac12\right\rfloor+\ldots+\left\lfloor\frac{x}{2^x}+\frac12\right\rfloor\;,
\end{align*}$$

and the problem is to show that this is equal to $x$ when $x$ is a positive integers. I don’t like using $x$ for integer variables, so I’m going to replace it with $n$: we want to show that

$$n=\sum_{k=1}^n\left\lfloor\frac{n+2^{k-1}}{2^k}\right\rfloor=\sum_{k=1}^n\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2^k}+\frac12\right\rfloor\tag{1}$$

for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$. One possibility that suggests itself immediately is induction on $n$. However, it turns out that ordinary induction, proceeding from $n$ to $n+1$, isn’t the best way to go. Instead I’ll use what is often called strong induction in elementary courses: I’ll assume that $(1)$ is true for all positive integers $n<m$ and show that the result is true for $m$ as well.

It turns out to be convenient to split this induction step into two cases, one for even $m$ and one for odd $m$. Suppose first that $m=2\ell$ is even. Then

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^m\left\lfloor\frac{m}{2^k}+\frac12\right\rfloor&=\sum_{k=1}^m\left\lfloor\frac{2\ell}{2^k}+\frac12\right\rfloor\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^m\left\lfloor\frac{\ell}{2^{k-1}}+\frac12\right\rfloor\\
&=\ell+\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}\left\lfloor\frac{\ell}{2^k}+\frac12\right\rfloor\\
&\overset{(*)}=\ell+\sum_{k=1}^\ell\left\lfloor\frac{\ell}{2^k}+\frac12\right\rfloor\\
&=2\ell\\
&=m
\end{align*}\tag{2}$$

by the induction hypothesis, since $\ell<m$. The starred step follows from the fact that if $k>\ell$, then

$$\left\lfloor\frac{\ell}{2^k}+\frac12\right\rfloor\le\left\lfloor\frac{\ell}{2^{\ell+1}}+\frac12\right\rfloor\le\left\lfloor\frac14+\frac12\right\rfloor=0\;.$$

Now let $m=2\ell+1$, and try to follow the same basic approach as in $(2)$.

Comment: Very true about the floor function comment in the answer. Nice answer anyways. +1